# Center a div next to another fixed div

Tags: css, html

I'm working on this layout:

```
<div id="outer">
   <div id="leftBar"></div>
   <div id="middleContainer">
      <div id="middle"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

with this stylesheet:

```
#outer{
    background-color:yellow;
    white-space:nowrap; 
}
#leftBar{
    background-color:purple;
    display:inline-block;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;   
}
#middle{
   background-color:blue;
   height:300px;
   width:100px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
#middleContainer{
    background-color:green;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/8ac2e/2/

There's a (purple) side bar that needs to stay fixed and a middle (blue) div that needs to be centered in the remaining space. I've wrapped the blue div in a (green) spacing div, but if I set its width to 100% then it overflows off the page so it doesn't flow correctly.

I've tried using absolute positioning of the side bar but that knocks the centering off too.

How to get the blue div to be centered in the remaining space? I'd rather not use float-left or float-right if possible.

Comment: remaining space from what? page or green div?

Comment: Thanks 4 fiddling, Overall you want ' to get the blue div to be centered' & 'purple side bar to stay fixed'.?

Comment: Why don't you want to use floats ?

Comment: @mehdi I'd like the green to fill the remaining space on the page and the blue to fit in the center of that space

Comment: @Fallup I hate floats and try to avoid them if at all possible

Comment: float is the best solution for that. And there is actualy no real reason to avoid floats or am I wrong?

Comment: @RiaElliger The evilness of floats or otherwise is a matter of opinion of course, I just prefer not to use them if I can help it.

Comment: I just want to know a reason. Maybe you are right and I don't know it yet... I just don't find a reason why they should be evil. So plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could absolutely position the left bar, and add a margin-left to the middleContainer equal to the width of the left bar and make the middleContainer display block. See http://jsfiddle.net/8ac2e/5/

```
#leftBar{
  background-color:purple;
  display:inline-block;
  height:300px;
  width:100px;
  position: absolute;
}
#middleContainer{
  background-color:green;
  margin-left:100px;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: works if the middleContainer is higher than the sidebar but breaks as soon as the sidebar wants to be higher

Comment: Good call. I just looked for a non-floating solution, and came up with that quickly. But floating might be the best way to solve this, until flexbox gains enough support.

Comment: but well, he hates floats for whatever reason ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is a classical situation for floats. It's just most flexible. Use `float: left` for the sidebar and `overflow: hidden` for your green middleContainer. This one takes the rest then. And change all `display: inline-block` to `display: block;`

http://jsfiddle.net/8ac2e/4/

This even works if your sidebar has flexible dimensions, the divs have different height and so on.

Comment: Apparently, Will Jenkins "hate floats and try to avoid them if at all possible." I didn't downvote by the way.

Comment: IF POSSIBLE. But to be honest, this is a classical float-situation and I think this solution is the only really clean way provided up to now (but I am open to other suggestions if you have one)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the browser support that you need to consider, you can use `calc()` to calculate the width of the `#middleContainer` by subtracting the width of the `#leftBar` from `100%` like this:

```
#middleContainer{
    background-color:green;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    height:100%; 
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ac2e/1/

More about calc() including browser support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: fancy and modern but right now it lacks browser support unfortunately. I think we have to wait for a couple of years to really use this :) But luckily you don't need it for the provided problem

Comment: Browser support for this isn't all that bad. If your user base on IE7-IE8 is low then it should be fine.

Comment: well I don't know your clients but I have to support IE8 every day and I hate it ;) But yeah, I like your solution (defenitely better then the accepted unflexible position:absolute one!) I just donÄt think the world is ready for this yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it using CSS table.

```
#container{
    display: table;
    background-color:yellow;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;

}
#leftBar{
    background-color:purple;
    display:table-cell;
    height:300px;
    width:20%;
}
#middle{

    background-color:blue;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#middleContainer{
    background-color:green;
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: yep, even this is better and more flexible then the accepted one :)